# Tiny Csv Parser - Parse negative int

Tags: c#, csv

Found this csv parser: https://github.com/bytefish/TinyCsvParser

Following his example but I even added one int property.
By setting a negative value to that int, it gave me one unvalid row.

Couldn't find any solution for this simple? problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type converter was using the wrong NumberStyle as default. I have fixed the problem and added a Test case to the project: https://github.com/bytefish/TinyCsvParser/issues/2.

You could also instantiate a custom converter with the right NumberStyle (see `WithCustomConverter`, [Example](http://bytefish.de/blog/tinycsvparser/)), but I suggest simply updating to the latest version (0.6), which is also updated in NuGet.